# Either I'm not confident or I just don't know anything

Tags: java, eclipse

Since I was 12 and I got my first computer I instantly go interested in making games.

Now, I have a basic understanding of java and how it works (it just clicked instantly one day). Anyways, my problem is that I know how I'm going to make a simple game in my head, but as soon as I click that "New Project" button on eclipse, I'm instantly lost and can't figure out where to start. I can't do much without a tutorial beside me since my mind is so dependent on it.

So here's the question: what can I do to get past this problem of mine, and have any of you felt like this before?

*I've made Minecraft mods before*

Edit:  Please don't tell me things like "You don't know what you're getting yourself into" or anything discouraging like that. I know that I can't make a AAA game by myself or any other popular indie game for that matter. I have been trying my best at developing my skills in java for nearly 2 years now, and I certainly don't bite off more than I can chew. I am not one of those children that comes in here and asks something like "How do i make a game like Minecraft". Also to specify my question a bit more here's a tiny summary.

Summary: Have any of you experienced this when you first started learning? Also how is it that you (Great and Mighty Critics) know what classes to make first?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Downvoting children, nice

Comment: No need to downvote this.

Comment: While it's good that you're learning to program, especially at a young age, StackOverflow is for specific programming questions. Buy a book on JAVA or read the official tutorials online, and then jump right in. If you have a specific problem, we'd be happy to help.

Comment: Because this person is a child does not mean they should be downvoted, but it doesn't mean it should be upvoted either. This question is asking for tutorials (MAYBE) on how to use Eclipse and such, I'm not sure what it is asking, hence downvote.

Comment: Also, eclipse is a nightmare for many, me included. consider something else if you're new. There are lots of editors. I like Notepad++ and Sublime.

Comment: @Plasmarob giving children wrong advice, nice. Eclipse FTW

Comment: Perhaps, start coding in a text editor, notepad, notepad++, or sublime.

Comment: let's not have editor wars. but you can't deny editor != IDE.

Comment: I would start with pencil and paper.  Sketch out your ideas of what you want to achieve and the objects that you might need.  Plain out how these might interact and would need to be managed. Try some simple ideas and see if you can get them to work.  Investigate some of the existing game engines and see if you can figure out how they work

Comment: @Plasmarob ctrl+space is not a keyboard shortcut, it is a way of life. I do not miss gedit/notepad++.

Comment: I think the question is not about Eclipse, but about how to organize and implement a standalone application like a game, isn’t it? I think a book an application and game development in Java will be the best way to deal with this.

Comment: if you do some more googling, there's a lot out there. I've heard Unity is best for gaming, if we're limiting it to that. @Robin

Comment: OP posted this same question here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/215946/either-im-not-confident-i-just-dont-know-anything. Please refrain from spamming stack, one place is enough.

Comment: @RobinKrahl should we warn him about the huge task? And to stay away from Java? Game engines have a lot of hardcore data-structures and mathematics in them (scene graph, transformations applied to normals that do not preserve the basis of the domain....) this is why I downvoted. I also don't think the Raspberry Pi is the solution the media touts it to be :P

Comment: I am sorry about this then topic then guys! And WOW you guys reply fast!I wish the best to you guys, and thanks for SOME nice answers.

Comment: Also even though i am still a child, it does not mean that i bite off more than i can chew. Every question that i search for has helped me alot, especially the ones that really go in depth for some algorithms.

Comment: As with any task; break it down into smaller tasks which don't depend on each other's internal workings (just that they do their job) then work on them one at a time,  testing each in isolation as you go. This avoids the feeling of being overwelmed as well as giving the program a good structure

Comment: @AlecTeal I don’t know why you reply to me, but I think if one is interested in this topic, is talented and has a clear aim, there is nothing bad about *trying*. But I don’t want to start a debate on principles on a closed question. ;)

Comment: @zoomerzoom25 Not really to discourage you. It's good to start in programming but, speaking of Game development, Physics and mathematics are required.

Comment: @Tdorno I am very so sorry, that did not show up in the search engine, nor did i find/see that topic on this site!

Comment: @Tdorno i didn't realize i posted it in 2 places

Comment: Sometmes when I'm overwhelmed I use the unimplemented methods technique (or interfaces for the advanced). I need an object to have a method; I create the method name but it justs has a throws unimplemented method exception if called. Then I use that method.  This allows me to create the whole logic of the program without getting bogged down in the actual implementation

Comment: @zoomerzoom25 It sounds like one thing you are missing is *patience*.  Learning to program takes a lot of time.  Unless you are unusually brilliant, it will take years for you to become truly comfortable with programming.  Patience is the best skill you can learn.  Build very small, modest games.  Nobody will want to play them, but that is where we all start.  Once your small game is done and working, you can move on to something new.  Type in programs for yourself, don't copy/paste.   Learn what every single character of your program does, even though it is boring to learn sometimes.

Comment: That would be my advice @MikeClark. I start to program when I was 9 years old in plain Basic and the first thing I could make was a program that ask me to type something then I printed it. After a little while I could understand more and was able to do my first game which was somekind of road and a dot to control and randow dots in the way that I had to deviate. So, start with something simplier like a hangman game then continue to improve your programming skills

Comment: @MikeClark Thank you for this! Although i really don't get bored by programming, i actually have a deep passion for it! I especially love it when i finally figure out a problem, and have that great moment of excitement!

Comment: @AlecTeal i am very sorry for not specifying the question well enough, and no i am not asking for a tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, know that what you have is *not* a problem.

Intelligence and capacity aside, programming is a science unique in comparison to others in the sense that is is as much an art as it is a science. It doesn't matter how many books you read or how many tutorials you do, it's more like painting or tennis in the sense that you just need to practice it daily to allow your brain the chance to develop that type of 'muscle memory'. When it comes to programming, nothing really beats 'experience'; there is only so much experience someone who is 12 can have.

Knowing that however, the fact that you know *what* you wan't to program is already "half the battle". Languages (Java,C++,etc.) are massive, instead of trying to 'master' a language to make something (e.g., a game) I would look for tools to help facilitate my task. In using the tool, you would learn the language by using the language, which I find is a much more constructive approach towards gaining programming experience (making a game from scratch using a bare IDE without any libraries is a daunting task, even for seasoned programmers).

Specifically for making games, you should try tools like:

- http://unity3d.com/
- http://www.yoyogames.com/studio

Unity3d in particular is programmed in C#, which you should have no trouble grasping if you're familiar with Java. The good thing about a tool like Unity is that there are plenty of pre-existing assets that you can use to jump start getting off the ground with your game. The community and the available references are also quite large.

The rest, is just practice. Unity for example has an enormous user interface with tons of features. Don't feel discouraged just because it feels complex. Just take it step by step, and know that it'll take time.

Best of luck

-- jdr

p.d.
If you're bored and care to spend 15 minutes reading something, read this:

theatlantic.com/education/archive/2013/10/the-myth-of-im-bad-at-math/280914/

It might not be about programming, but it's the same difference.

Comment: To add to those librarys jmonkey is also good for 3D games in java (and obscenely easy to start using because it comes with its own IDE (based on netbeans) with all the the dependencys included

Comment: This answer was amazing!I would rather use Unity than game maker though, i have used Game Maker before, and got bored by the simplicity of it. I've also devoted a few months to practicing blender, and audacity, so Unity would suit me best! Thank you again for the terrific answer, and i wish the best to you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you just need to spend some time doing some tutorials and getting familiar with the eclipse environment.

A good place to start with eclipse is [The Getting Started Section](http://www.eclipse.org/resources/?category=Getting%20Started). I would recommend watching the [Using the Eclipse Workbench video](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/workbench.html) as the first step.

Unfortunately there's no quick learn option, I find videos a nice way to get quickly familiar with new products and technologies.

I hope this answer helps you on your way, next time a more specific question may help you get clearer answers :).

Comment: Thank you very much John! This certainly does help a bit. My problem is that i don't know how to start my project. Anyhow, thank you for the help!

Comment: Start as in, which classes to start making

Comment: Do you even know the rules of the game you are building? :)  You should figure out the specifics of how your game will work before you start trying to program it.  Programmers often do what we call "refactoring" -- it means we write the code in an easy way that just works, then go back later and give the classes and methods pretty names.   You can start with just `MyClass` and `main`.